# Safari renders white boxes. Tried flexBasis:0 to entire list

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, safari, material-ui

I have  a problem with Safari on iOS

[image: White boxes]

As you can see some boxes are white, but when I try to change the CSS inside the content appears.

There is no strange stuff, only react materialUI and a list, see the code of the element

```
       <div class="MuiCardContent-root" style="position: relative;">
           <div class="flex flex-row">
                   <div><img src="..."></div>
                   <div class="main-text">
                           <div class="title">Tipologie di approccio</div>
                           <div class="subtitle">Qual è il più adatto a te?</div>
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to apply `flexBasis:0` to the entire list as suggested over git hub but i have no idea on how to manage this bug... is it a safari render problem?

thanks guys!